# Are Ads API city keys static?

Tags: performance, facebook-ads-api

I need to look up large sets of city codes, but the Ads API isn't well suited to this.  (I can't submit batches larger than 50.  If I query it too rapidly, it doesn't always return valid responses.)  The best solution may be to cache the results.

So, my question is, how long should I cache the results?  Are the key values static?  Or do they change on occasion when new cities are added?

Also, Is there a better approach than caching?